# MySQL user defined variable and ORDER BY on a dynamic column

Tags: mysql, sql

This query :

```
SET @position := 0;
SELECT 
    (@position:=@position + 1),
    (statistics.value - statistics_logs.value) AS value_new
FROM
    rankings AS r
        LEFT JOIN
    rankings_logs AS rl ON statistics_logs.name = statistics.name
        AND statistics_logs.user_id = statistics.user_id
ORDER BY value_new DESC
```

... doesn't give the expected result which is supposed to be :

```
"(@position := @position + 1)"  value_new
1   10
2   20
3   30
4   40
5   50
```

Instead, it returns the stranges results :

```
"(@position := @position + 1)"  value_new
4   10
2   20
3   30
1   40
5   50
```

I think it's because value_new is generated from a soustraction of two values in differents tables, and that the `ORDER BY` happen somehow after `position` has been defined. But I don't know how to fix this. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a subquery will work:

```
SELECT (@position:=@position + 1), value_new
FROM (SELECT (statistics.value - statistics_logs.value) AS value_new
      FROM rankings r LEFT JOIN
           rankings_logs rl
           ON rl.name = r.name AND sl.user_id = s.user_id
      ORDER BY value_new DESC
     ) cross join
     (select @position := 0) vars;
```